# AngularJS Add - remove classes from ng-repeat list

Tags: angularjs

Colleagues, there is such an example for clarity.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.li-example')].forEach((s, i, arr) => {
  s.addEventListener('click', function() {
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.li-example')].forEach((s, i, arr) => {
      arr[i].classList.remove('li-example-active');
    })
    arr[i].classList.add('li-example-active');
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #222;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

menu {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #999;
  margin: 15px;
}

li.li-example {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #cc0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
li.li-example-active{
  background-color: #00c;
}
```

```html
<menu class="example">
  <li class="li-example"><span>Example</span></li>
  <li class="li-example"><span>Example</span></li>
  <li class="li-example"><span>Example</span></li>
  <li class="li-example"><span>Example</span></li>
  <li class="li-example"><span>Example</span></li>
</menu>
```

I do not think that it is necessary to explain what is happening in the example above.

And an example on AngularJS

```js
const app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('example', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "C",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.myExample = ['Example-1', 'Example-2', 'Example-3', 'Example-4', 'Example-5'];
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #222;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

menu {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #999;
  margin: 15px;
}

li.li-example {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #cc0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5vmax;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

li.li-example-active {
  background-color: #00c;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<menu class="example">
  <li class="li-example" ng-repeat="example in myExample"
      ng-click="active = !active" 
      ng-class="active ? '' : 'li-example-active'">
      <span>{{example}}</span>
  </li>
</menu>
<html>
```

And how in this variant to implement this example as in the first classical variant JS ???? So that the element that was clicked was assigned the class `li-example-active`, and the rest was removed the class`li-example-active` ???

Comment: you use your models property `active` for all your elements. you should obviously save the active state on each of your elements (or in an array which holds the state)

Comment: @lexith, I started learning `Angular` for 2 days, and I have a bad idea of what you are telling me, will it not make it difficult for you to set an example?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are starting to learn angularjs instead of angular? Anyway, you loop through your `myExample` array. So in every iteration check on the element you iterate through if it's `active` like `ng-click="example.active = !example.active" ng-class="example.active ...."`

Comment: @lexith, nothing works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array and a function to manipulate that array.

Use them in the HTML

```
<menu class="example">
  <li class="li-example" ng-repeat="example in myExample"
      ng-click="makeActive($index)" 
      ng-class="{'li-example-active': activeArr[$index]}">
      <span>{{example}}</span>
  </li>
</menu>
```

Implement them in a controller:

```
app.controller('example', function($scope) {
     $scope.myExample = ['Example-1', 'Example-2', 'Example-3', 'Example-4', 'Example-5'];
     $scope.activeArr = $scope.myExample.map(_ => false);
     $scope.makeActive=function(index) {
         Object.keys($scope.activeArr).forEach( _ => {
              $scope.activeArr[_] = (_ == index);
         });
     };
});
```

### The DEMO

```js
const app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('example', function($scope) {
     $scope.myExample = ['Example-1', 'Example-2', 'Example-3', 'Example-4', 'Example-5'];
     $scope.activeArr = $scope.myExample.map(_ => false);
     $scope.makeActive=function(index) {
         Object.keys($scope.activeArr).forEach( _ => {
              $scope.activeArr[_] = (_ == index);
         });
     };
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #222;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

menu {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #999;
  margin: 15px;
}

li.li-example {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #cc0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5vmax;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

li.li-example-active {
  background-color: #00c;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="example">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<menu class="example">
  <li class="li-example" ng-repeat="example in myExample"
      ng-click="makeActive($index)" 
      ng-class="{'li-example-active': activeArr[$index]}">
      <span>{{example}}</span>
  </li>
</menu>
<html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answer is very expensive. I learned a lot from him. Even what is not in this question, but was going to ask a question ... Thanks again ...